# Codeigniter - How to call file without USE statement

Tags: php, codeigniter

The original code,

```
function sendSMS()
{
    require './Twilio/autoload.php';

    # Error having now
    use Twilio\Rest\Client; 

    $sid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    $token = 'your_auth_token';
    $client = new Client($sid, $token);
    ...
}
```

In above **we cant use USE statement inside the function**(cant load outside the controller function too. check Note 01).

I tried

```
public function sendSMS()
{
    require './Twilio/autoload.php';
    require './Twilio/Rest/Client.php';
```

But No use....

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>   Type: Error
>   Message: Class 'Client' not found

---

**Question :** To achieve this `$client = new Client($sid, $token);` is there any alternative that i can load the file?

---

**Note 01**

```
use Twilio\Rest\Client; 
function sendSMS()
{
    require './Twilio/autoload.php';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using

`use Twilio\Rest\Client;`

Change this line

`$client = new Client($sid, $token);`

to

`$client = new Twilio\Rest\Client($sid, $token);`